# Get and Display path of Chosen photo from gallery in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using a Dependency service to pick a photo from the gallery. and I want to show the path when the user selects an image from their phone in a Label.

I have read too many logs but not getting the proper results.
I want it like this:

[image]

Now the selected image is displayed properly but what I don't get is how to display the path of the selected image.

Please suggest me how to do it for both android and ios.

**Note**: I'm using Dependency service for it so I don't want third-party plugins.

I hope I will get a better solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope. I want path lik this: storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_202001.jpg this means if i select image from WhatsApp folder then it should return path as it stored. Above path is of photo  
Captured from android phone's camera  can you give me the solution for this ???

Answer (score 1):

#### Creating the interface in forms

```
namespace xxx
{
    public interface IPhotoPickerService
    {
        Task<Dictionary<string,Stream>> GetImageStreamAsync();
    }
}
```

#### in iOS

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (PhotoPickerService))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class PhotoPickerService : IPhotoPickerService
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<Dictionary<string, Stream>> taskCompletionSource;
        UIImagePickerController imagePicker;

        Task<Dictionary<string, Stream>> IPhotoPickerService.GetImageStreamAsync()
        {
            // Create and define UIImagePickerController
            imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController
            {
                SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary,
                MediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.AvailableMediaTypes(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
            };

            // Set event handlers
            imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia;
            imagePicker.Canceled += OnImagePickerCancelled;

            // Present UIImagePickerController;
            UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
            var viewController = window.RootViewController;
            viewController.PresentModalViewController(imagePicker, true);

            // Return Task object
            taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Dictionary<string, Stream>>();
            return taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }

       

        void OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs args)
        {
            UIImage image = args.EditedImage ?? args.OriginalImage;

            if (image != null)
            {
                // Convert UIImage to .NET Stream object
                NSData data;
                if (args.ReferenceUrl.PathExtension.Equals("PNG") || args.ReferenceUrl.PathExtension.Equals("png"))
                {
                    data = image.AsPNG();
                }
                else
                {
                    data = image.AsJPEG(1);
                }
                Stream stream = data.AsStream();

                UnregisterEventHandlers();

                Dictionary<string, Stream> dic = new Dictionary<string, Stream>();
                dic.Add(args.ImageUrl.ToString(), stream);

                // Set the Stream as the completion of the Task
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(dic);
            }
            else
            {
                UnregisterEventHandlers();
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            }
            imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
        }

        void OnImagePickerCancelled(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            UnregisterEventHandlers();
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
        }

        void UnregisterEventHandlers()
        {
            imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia -= OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia;
            imagePicker.Canceled -= OnImagePickerCancelled;
        }

        
    }
}
```

#### in Android

**in MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    ...
    // Field, property, and method for Picture Picker
    public static readonly int PickImageId = 1000;

    public TaskCompletionSource<Dictionary<string,Stream>> PickImageTaskCompletionSource { set; get; }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (requestCode == PickImageId)
        {
            if ((resultCode == Result.Ok) && (intent != null))
            {
                Android.Net.Uri uri = intent.Data;
                Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);

                Dictionary<string, Stream> dic = new Dictionary<string, Stream>();
                dic.Add(uri.ToString(), stream);
                // Set the Stream as the completion of the Task
                PickImageTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(dic);
            }
            else
            {
                PickImageTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PhotoPickerService))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class PhotoPickerService : IPhotoPickerService
    {
        public Task<Dictionary<string,Stream>> GetImageStreamAsync()
        {
            // Define the Intent for getting images
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetType("image/*");
            intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);

            // Start the picture-picker activity (resumes in MainActivity.cs)
            MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(
                Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                MainActivity.PickImageId);

            // Save the TaskCompletionSource object as a MainActivity property
            MainActivity.Instance.PickImageTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Dictionary<string,Stream>>();

            // Return Task object
            return MainActivity.Instance.PickImageTaskCompletionSource.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

#### invoke it

```
Dictionary<string, Stream> dic = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoPickerService>().GetImageStreamAsync();

Stream stream;
string path;

foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, Stream> currentImage in dic )
{
   stream = currentImage.Value;

   path = currentImage.Key;

   label.Text = path;

   if (stream != null)
   {
      image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
   }
}
```

#### Update

If you want to get the path , you could invoke

```
Dictionary<string, Stream> dic = new Dictionary<string, Stream>();
dic.Add(uri.Path, stream);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But By using this i am getting different path like this: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A86014 This path is tidy to see for users. I want to display local path like where our images are stored. e.g: Internal storage/DCIM/Screenshorts/Screenshorts_2020-01-08_com.whatsapp.png  Have you any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Because you select  the image from gallery.

Comment: yes if your answer will satisfy my condition then ya i would do it

Comment: This looked great, but I get `"/document/image:9982"` in stead of an actual path, is there a way to fix this ?